# Show Base64String image as MapIcon image in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

I converted images to base64 string and saved to the SQLite database. I want to show that image in the map.

Code used to convert String to image

```
    public static BitmapImage Base64StringToBitmap(string source)
    {
        var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
        var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
        dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
        dataWriter.StoreAsync();
        ims.Seek(0);
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(ims);
        return img;
    }
```

How can I show this image in map. Showing pushpins

```
    private void loadPushpin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var query = dbConn.Table<Contacts>();
            var result = query.ToList();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                 Contacts obj = new Contacts();
                 MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
                 MapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(""));
                 MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                 {
                     Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.Latitude),
                     Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.Longitude)
                 });
                   MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
                   MapIcon1.Title = item.Name;
                 MyLocationMap.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CreateFromStream and pass InMemboryRandomeAccessStream instead of CreateFromUri. Below is the code

```
  var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
        var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
        dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
        dataWriter.StoreAsync();
        ims.Seek(0);
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(ims);
        return img;

        MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
        MapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(ims);;
```

**Update**

```
   private async void loadPushpin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
    {
        var query = dbConn.Table<Contacts>();
        var result = query.ToList();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
             Contacts obj = new Contacts();
             MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
             {
                 Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.Latitude),
                 Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(item.Longitude)
             });

            var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(item.ImageString);//set your image base 64 string here...
            var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            ims.Seek(0);

           MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
           MapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(ims);


               MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
               MapIcon1.Title = item.Name;
             MyLocationMap.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit how to do so. I updated my code in the question

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. one small thing, how can I change the image properties (size of the image).

Comment: You cannot change the size of mapIcon image as it is Stream. In this case use samller or larger image in you database.